# How do you temporarily hide a table in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, background, modal-dialog

I need to display a different background when a modal shows up so I need to hide the table until the user submits the form in the modal. Any ideas? I can't find any `show` or `hide` attributes for a Table.

Table

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import SampleQ from '../components/question.js';
import css from '../scss/style.scss';
import Layout from '../components/layout';

export default class extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showBackground: false
        };

        this.showBackground = () => {
            this.setState({ showBackground: true });
        };

        this.hideBackground = () => {
            this.setState({ showBackground: false });
        }
    }

    static getInitialProps({query: {categories, questions, answers}}) {
        return {postCs: categories, allQs: questions, allAs: answers}
    }

    createTable = () => {
        let table = [];

        let cats = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < this.props.postCs.length; i++){
            cats.push(<th key = {i}>{this.props.postCs[i].title}</th>);
        }

        table.push(<thead> <tr> {cats} </tr> </thead>);

        let index = 0;
        // Outer loop to create parent
        for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            let children = [];

            //Inner loop to create children
            for (let j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
                children.push(
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <SampleQ
                                amount={i}
                                question={this.props.allQs[(index)].title}
                                answer={this.props.allAs[(index)].title}
                                showBackdrop={this.showBackground}
                                hideBackdrop={this.hideBackground}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </td>);
                index++;
            }
            //Create the parent and add the children
            table.push(<tr>{children}</tr>)
        }

        return table
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Layout showBackground={this.state.showBackground} title="lllll" />
                <Table striped bordered hover variant = "dark" className={css.table} hide={true}>
                    {this.createTable()}
                </Table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html), e.g.

```
render () {
  return (
    <Modal>
      {isFormSubmitted ? <Table /> : null}
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Comment: If I do conditional rendering with a ternary operator, the modals which should pop up upon pressing the cell on my table don't anymore because the table is not rendered. I've updated my post with some code for context.